# Laravel 5.5: how to get failed job ID and link it to the related object?

Tags: laravel-5, queue, jobs

In Laravel 5.5, I've created a queue job like this:

```
class EmailJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    private $emailModel;

    /**
    * Create a new job instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function __construct(MyEmail $emailModel)
    {
        //
        $this->emailModel = $emailModel;
    }

    // ...
}
```

- `MyEmail` is a model to store email data.
- I use `database` driver on queue.

Now, I want to catch the failed job (in `failed_jobs` table), and link them to related `MyEmail` object (e.g: store in an attribute `failed_job_id`), then later on my app can manually retry specific email's failed job. How can I achieve this ?

---

I have a workaround approach, in which I grab all failed jobs through `failed_jobs` table, and check the payload one by one, determine if the `MyEmail` object has the `id` we want. but I don't think it's efficient.